# unable to choose hdfs file under upload table tab (Hive view - Ambari)

Tags: azure, hive, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm using Hortonworks-sandbox in Azure.
When I clicked browse button under the upload table tab in Hive view (Ambari), I can upload files from my local file system (not sandbox local fs). And I'm not able to select files from HDFS. There is no such option to select files from HDFS in the Interface.
Is there any way to select files from HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select files from HDFS if by selecting files you mean being able to upload files.

No, you cannot select files from HDFS if by selecting files you mean being able to graphically choose them.

Back to being able to select files: you should see an `HDFS Path: Enter full HDFS path` box. Enter there the path where you uploaded the data file. For example `/user/[user_name]/[file_name]`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem , it is likely you are using HDP version 2.4 , like me.

I was following tutorials for HDP 2.5, so you should instead refer to this one (specific to HDP 2.4):

https://github.com/hortonworks/tutorials/tree/hdp-2.4/tutorials/hortonworks/hello-hdp-an-introduction-to-hadoop